# How to create and configure a sinon stub in a single command

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing

If I want to create and configure a Sinon stub in a single line, is it possible? The naive implementation:

```
const a = sinon.stub().withArgs(myArg1).returns(15);
```

doesn't set `a` to the stub- it sets it to `15`. I would like `a` to be equivalent to

```
const a = sinon.stub();
a.withArgs(myArg1).returns(15);
```

I have looked through the docs but nothing jumped out at me - is what I want possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature of `returns` method for `"sinon": "^8.1.1"`:

```js
returns(obj: TReturnValue): SinonStub<TArgs, TReturnValue>;
```

So the return value of the `returns` method is a sinon stub. E.g.

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('56876050', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const a = sinon
      .stub()
      .withArgs('myArg1')
      .returns(15);
    const actual = a();
    expect(actual).to.eql(15);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(a);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
  56876050
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (8ms)
```